# .NET - Computing SHA512 with SHA512Managed - Why two "==" when converting to string?

Tags: vb.net, sha512

For some reason everytime i compute a sha512 hash and convert it to a string, the two last characters are ==. Any idea why?

```
Function GetSHA512FromStringAsString(ByVal strdata As String)
    Dim data As Byte() = StringToByte(strdata)
    Dim result() As Byte
    Dim shaM As New SHA512Managed()
    result = shaM.ComputeHash(data)

    Return ByteToString(result)
End Function


Function ByteToString(ByVal dBytes() As Byte)
        Dim strText = Convert.ToBase64String(dBytes)
        Return strText
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Base64 strings can end in = or == based on the number of bytes being encoded. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding

Answer (score 0):

It's the Base64 padding you see: Base64 transforms groups of 4 bytes in 3 bytes, which means that the last encoded group will not always be complete - depending on the length of the input string it will contain 1, 2 or 3 bytes.  This is solved by padding, and the `==` you see here is caused by having just 1 used byte in the last encoded group of 3.

The full explanation can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)

Comment: But the hash does have 64 bytes, from 0-63.

Comment: @WoF_Angel And 64 mod 3 is ? ... Exactly  :-)